# change in TCP packet size in ns3

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, tcpdump, ns-3

I am a new ns3 user. The program [sixth.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/sixth_8cc_source.html) generates a pcap file

```
1.136956 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 17177:17681, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 1133 ecr 1127,eol], length 504: HTTP
1.403196 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 33280:33784, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 1399 ecr 1394,eol], length 504: HTTP
1.436476 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 37440:37944, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 1432 ecr 1428,eol], length 504: HTTP
2.533823 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 174184:174720, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 2530 ecr 2525,eol], length 536: HTTP
2.543036 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 175760:176264, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 2539 ecr 2534,eol], length 504: HTTP
2.608703 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 183544:184080, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 2605 ecr 2600,eol], length 536: HTTP
5.804476 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 583440:583944, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 5800 ecr 5796,eol], length 504: HTTP
6.453436 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 664560:665064, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 6449 ecr 6445,eol], length 504: HTTP
7.367743 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 778424:778960, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 7364 ecr 7360,eol], length 536: HTTP
7.393596 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 782080:782584, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 7389 ecr 7386,eol], length 504: HTTP
8.158143 IP 10.1.1.1.49153 > 10.1.1.2.8080: Flags [.], seq 877224:877760, ack 1, win 32768, options [TS val 8155 ecr 8149,eol], length 536: HTTP
```

Can anyone explain me if the MSS is changing from 536 bytes to  504 bytes and if so why?

Answer (score 0):

The pcap file generated in sixth.cc only shows packets that have been dropped. The default MSS is 536 bytes, so that's why the largest packet dropped is of that size. It just so happens that TCP decided to transmit segments of 504 bytes as well, and the corresponding packets were dropped by the receiver. Then later, the same happened with 536 byte segments as well.

Naturally, the next question is: why did TCP decide to transmit a 504 byte segment in one case, and a 536 segment in another? I haven't debugged the program to verify this, but my speculation is that TCP's buffer only had 504 bytes to send, so that's all it sent. The MSS is a *maximum* segment size (not a *minimum*), so TCP can send packets smaller than 536 bytes. You can try to verify this by either

- setting breakpoints in TcpSocketBase, or
- [enabling debug messages](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.30/manual/html/logging.html) for TcpSocketBase, and looking for messages about Nagle's algorithm being invoked.

So, the MSS is not changing, but the size of the segment transmitted does change. Smaller 504 byte segments were probably transmitted since that's all TCP had in its buffer to send at that given time.

### Other details

On lines 208-210, a RateErrorModel is instantiated, and associated with the device 1. This model will randomly drop packets at the receiver NetDevice. So, in this simulation, packets may be dropped due to a buffer overflow, or randomly due to the RateErrorModel.

On lines 238-240, the PhyRxDrop TraceSource associated with device 1 is connected to `RxDrop`. A Callback to `RxDrop` is instantiated with one bound argument. The bound argument is a PcapFileWrapper, which can be thought of as a class that encapsulates a file, and makes adding packets to a pcap file easy.